# Google KmlLayer not displaying custom marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I've written an R script to create a KML file and the resultant KML below loads icon18.png fine when viewed in Google Earth:

```
   <kml xmlns:xsd="http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd" xmlns:xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2/" version="1.0">
      <Document>
        <name>Member locations</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Folder>
      <name>SpatialPointsDataFrame</name>
      <Style id="pnt1">
        <IconStyle>
          <Icon>
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon18.png</href>
          </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
          <text>$[description]</text>
        </BalloonStyle>
      </Style>
      <Placemark>
        <name>1</name>
        <styleUrl>#pnt1</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <extrude>1</extrude>
          <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
          <coordinates>151.26250,-33.89374,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

However when loaded into a KmlLayer using the maps API and the following code it displays as the default blue 'teardrop' marker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.peter-johnson.com.au/test.kml');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looking at other questions here I could only see ones posted without code that went unanswered or some related to the web server not being publically available.
A few indiciated there problem was now OK so I guess loading custom icons into a KmlLayer is supported but I have some problem with the KML format or the way I'm loading it?

As suggested in a comment I've just placed the KML in a publically available area here:

http://www.peter-johnson.com.au/test.kml

And here is the HTML:

http://www.peter-johnson.com.au/test.htm

Comment: Can you post the public link to the KML that you are using with KmlLayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KML you have posted doesn't work with either [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FcustomIconKml_SOa_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.641638,0.883026&t=m&z=10) or [KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/customIconKml_SOa_kml.xml) even after I make it [validate](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FcustomIconKml_SOa_kml.xml)

- [Your KML on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.peter-johnson.com.au%2Ftest.kml&hl=en&t=m&z=19) - Blue default marker
- [Your KML on Google Maps API v3 map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.peter-johnson.com.au/test.kml) - Blue default marker

For what it is worth, it does [work with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/customIconKml_SOa_kml.xml)

Your version does have an invalid schema (at least according to [feedvalidator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.peter-johnson.com.au%2Ftest.kml))

**UPDATE:**
The problem is with the location of the definition of the shared styles.

[This](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/peter-johnson_com_au_testA.kml) [works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/peter-johnson_com_au_testA.kml) and on [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fpeter-johnson_com_au_testA.kml&hl=en&sll=37.6,-95.665&sspn=54.71142,78.046875&t=m&z=19)

The [Style](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#style) definition didn't work where you had it.  [Shared styles](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#document) look like they have to be in a Document.